# A python module is found normaly when the python script runs from terminal but its not found when the same script is called in a bash script.Why?

Tags: python, bash, python-module

(newbee here,i couldnt find something similar)So, I have a python script that sents an email with attachments to some recipients and works fine when I run it straight from the terminal. But when I call this script in a bash script I get an error that the Module below is not found. Why is that? (on a Mac if that matters)

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.MIMEMultipart'
```

Comment: open the terminal, cd into the directory where your code is, and try running it

Comment: You are going to have to provide more details. How exactly is your bash script running your python script? Do you have multiple interpreters on your machine?

Comment: I have python 2.7 and python 3.6 on my mac but this script starts with #!/usr/bin/python that is actually python 2.7 (if that helps)

Comment: Show your bash script please, or at lease where it calls the python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So on my mac I had two versions of python:

Python 3.6 lives in:

```
/Users/name/anaconda/bin/python
```

While Python 2.7 lives in:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

My python_script.py , that was running fine when it was called on its own in the terminal, was calling Python 2.7 and had the following shebang/firstline:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

In my bash script, the line that was calling python_script.py was a follows:

```
python /directory/directory/python_script.py
```

The code was not working on this implimentation because when you type python in the terminal it acually starts Python 3.6 instead of Python 2.7 that my python_script.py was using (I had the wrong idea that the default system Python would be Python 2.7 that my mac came with). The solution (as per Stack suggestion above) was to cd in directory I had my python_script.py and then run it from there by just typing:

```
./python_script.py
```

Hope this helps someone, someday.

---

(I should have probably deleted this post because I keep getting downvotes for some reasion but i will leave it for other newbees like me)